# Запрос на сервер android

Tags: android

Ребят помогите разобраться имеется код:

```
FILENAME= "file";
            url = new URL("https://123123");
            new ParseTask().execute();
            url = new URL("https://3333333");
            FILENAME="file1";
            new ParseTask().execute();
 public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ошибка подключения к инетрнету", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            writeFile(strJson);
        }

    }
```

Он почему-то пропускает первую ссылку и выполняет код со 2 и со 2 файлом. Почему так? И toast не работает почему-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присвоения значений переменным и вызовы метода `execute` происходят синхронно, а вот вызов `doInBackground` метода - асинхронно. Засим на момент вызова последнего переменной `url` присвоено уже второе значение.

Вам надо передавать `url` в конструктор задачи чтобы не возникало таких проблем.

Также не следует тоаст показывать из `doInBackground` - этот метод должен только что-то качать. Проверяете в `onPostExecute` что вам что-то пришло. Если ничего не пришло - показывайте тоаст с ошибкой.

---

Чтобы передать что-то в конструктор - делайте так:

```
public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private String url;

    public ParseTask(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //тут доступна переменная url, значение которой задано при создании экземпляра класса
    }
}
```

Соответственно, при создании экземпляра класса-задачи передавайте так:

```
new ParseTask("http://some.domain.ru").execute();
```

Comment: А можете для примера показать, как передать url в конструктор задачи?

Comment: @Сашка, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое)